# Whether the dagger recognize the interface to be injected while using constructor injection?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I understand that the constructor injection can be used to avoid the declartion of module for downstream injections.

For example, by adding the scope and inject annotation , I don't need to write the module to provide the instance.

```
@Singleton
public class Injection {
   @Inject
   Injection ( Dependency dependency ) {...}
}
```

so I can get instance by using following annotation in other class

```
@inject
Injection myInjection;
```

However, is it possible that I can get the same result if I want it be injected from interface declare?

such as :

```
@Singleton
public class Injection implement InjectionInterface {
   @Inject
   Injection (Dependency dependency) {...}
}

@inject 
InjectionInterface myInjection; // will I get the instance of Injection?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to create a module for that

```
@Module
public class MyModule {
    InjectionInterface injectionInterface(Injection injection) {
        return injection;
    }
}
```

You can also use `@Binds` which does exactly the same thing.

```
@Module
public abstract class MyModule {
    @Binds
    abstract InjectionInterface injectionInterface(Injection injection);
}
```